# How to avoid multiple if to check different conditions

Tags: jquery, oop, if-statement

There are multiple `if` statements in my code like following:

```
if ($('#text1').val().length == 0) {
    $('#text1').val(text1);
}
if ($('#text2').val().length == 0) {
    $('#text2').val(text2);
}
if ($('#text3').val().length == 0) {
    $('#text3').val(text3);
}
if ($('#text4').val().length == 0) {
    $('#text4').val(text4);
}
if ($('#text5').val().length == 0) {
    $('#text5').val(text5);
}
if ($('#text6').val().length == 0) {
    $('#text6').val(text6);
}
```

So based on the requirement I need to check if there is a value in the textbox then don't overwrite the API response, otherwise write the API response. Is there any way to avoid these many `if` to improve the performance ?

Comment: use a switch - case?a loop?

Comment: Put the `textN` values in an array and loop over them. You can easily associate the input elements to the values by index

Answer (score 1):

Use a common class or attribute selector if for some reason you cannot, then the logic would be:

```
$('[id^=text]').val(function(){
  return this.value.length ? this.value : data[this.id];
});
```

```js
var data = {
  text1: 1,
  text2: 2,
  text3: 3
}

$('[id^=text]').val(function(){
  return this.value.length ? this.value : data[this.id];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text1" value="">
<input id="text2" value="">
<input id="text3" value="ok">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `each` method and [[attribute^=value]](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_beginning_value.asp) selector:

```
$("[id^=text]").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).val($(this).attr(id));
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){

if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
    $('#text1').val(text1);
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something using a looping like:

```
var textN = [text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6];

for(var i = 1; i <= textN.length; i++){
    var textID = '#text' + i;
    if ($(textID).val().length == 0) {
        $(textID).val(textN[i - 1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var i=0;
while(i<elementcount)
{
  if($('#text'+i).val().length == 0)
    if($('#text'+i).val(textarray[i]);
  i++;
}
```

but first you define the element count and textarray. hope this concept helps